# Increase web scraper efficiency

Tags: java, elasticsearch, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am creating a java application to scrape data from a particular XXX website and I want to store a desired set of data into my MSSQL database. The dataset is around 100000+ rows in MSSQL.

What I do is I scrape the data, process it according to my requirement, and then I store it in DB as well as my ElasticSearch set. The whole process takes around 2 days or more for a single run. I use JSoup for parsing data.

What I want to know is that how can I increase the efficiency of my application so that I can scrape it and save it in lesser time. I have executor services for parallel execution of my process.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hand-crafting such an application, you can rely on distributed Web-crawler technology such as [StormCrawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler). It is even capable of indexing the pages into an ElasticSearch instance.

If you want to store additional information, you can easily implement a custom `Bolt` for the MSSQL part of your process. However, using this framework requires setting up a Apache Storm cluster environment, which might take some time and computational ressources. This will speed up the process you described above drastically.